# Android cloud to device messaging basics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to add cloud to device messaging to my app. Is it necessary to write a service?
I closed all running services about whatsapp viber etc. then i tried to send message on whatsapp to my phone when whatsapp and its services are closed. My message is delivered.
So this means service is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to write a service?

In most cases, yes. It depends a bit on what you are trying to do in response to the GCM message.

> My message is delivered. So this means service is not necessary.

No, this means that some sort of continuously-running service is not necessary.

GCM messages are delivered as broadcasts. A manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` is necessary, as is described (poorly) in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest).

However, the `onReceive()` method of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread, and so if the work in response to a GCM message will be more than a few milliseconds, we cannot do that work on `onReceive()` without introducing jank into our UI, should our UI happen to be in the foreground. And, since a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` is only considered to be running while `onReceive()` is called, we cannot safely fork our own thread, as our process may be terminated before the thread can wrap up.

Hence, the `BroadcastReceiver` that receives the GCM message often times will delegate the actual work to an `IntentService`. This too is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest).

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. I want to show the header of a new announcement via GCM and when user clicks notification I want to show body of announcement in my app. In this case do you think is a service necessary?

Comment: @BilalTürk: If you do not need to do any disk I/O to create your `Notification`, that should be quick enough to just do in `onReceive()`. However, you may want to use an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus) to handle the case when the GCM message comes in and your app is already in the foreground.